# RESTful web services in java

Tags: java, xml, rest, post

I am trying to pass list of `Long` in my resource as post data and consume type is `application/xml`. I am also passing two path params. It is giving me exception "media type not supported".

Please help me to solve this.
this is the code and I am having exception..

```
@POST
    @Path("/temp/{abc}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Long> createUser2(List<User> users,@PathParam("abc") String abc) {
//.................//
        List<Long> listLong=new ArrayList<Long>();
        listLong.add(1L);
        listLong.add(2L);
        System.out.println("temp called");
        return listLong;
    }




> org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:
> MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml
```

Comment: Could you show us some of your code that sends the data to the API?

Comment: We are not omniscient.

Comment: @POST
    @Path("/temp/{abc}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Long> createUser2(List<User> users,@PathParam("abc")                String abc) {
//.................//
        List<Long> listLong=new ArrayList<Long>();
        listLong.add(1L);
        listLong.add(2L);
        System.out.println("temp called");
        return listLong;
    }

this is the code and I am getting this exception

org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml

Comment: If you have used Restful webservices before...then the question was enough explanatory..because list of long type will not transfer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that there's no conversion code that knows how to automatically change a `Long` or a `List<Long>` into XML. At the very least, information about what the name of the containing element *must* be present, and JAXB (the default supported mechanism) only applies that sort of thing at the level of a class.

The fix is to create a wrapper class with suitable JAXB annotations and return that. You might need to tweak the class to get exactly the serialization you want, but that's not hard.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "userinfo")
public class UserInfo {
    @XmlElement
    public List<Long> values;
    // JAXB really requires a no-argument constructor...
    public UserInfo() {}
    // Convenience constructor to make the code cleaner...
    public UserInfo(List<Long> theList) {
        values = theList;
    }
}
```

```
@POST
@Path("/temp/{abc}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
// NOTE THE CHANGE OF RESULT TYPE
public UserInfo createUser2(List<User> users,@PathParam("abc") String abc) {
    //.................//
    List<Long> listLong=new ArrayList<Long>();
    listLong.add(1L);
    listLong.add(2L);
    System.out.println("temp called");
    return new UserInfo(listLong); // <<<< THIS LINE CHANGED TOO
}
```

Comment: Were you returning a single `Long`, I'd say send it as plain text (mapping `null` to the empty string).

Comment: great..thank you very much..Can you tell me some other way for it? If my rest client is in some other language like javascript, then how It will change this UserInfo to the list again?

Comment: on client side it is not sending 
  `String xml = null;
        try {            
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(user, stringWriter);
            xml = stringWriter.toString();

        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UmsClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        String result = client.sendPostRequestXmlData2("user", xml);`
giving exception

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.tm.ums.model.UserInfo nor any of its super class is known to this context.